# EXPO REACT-NATIVE STRIPE PAYMENT 'expo-payments-stripe': How to use a token created?

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

I can generate a token with the createTokenWithCardAsync function, but then I don't know how to use the token to go through with the payment process.

Would anyone know which functions are in the 'expo-payments-stripe'? The actual stripe functions like stripe.customers.create() or stripe.charges.create() do not work. So far I just know of 2 functions compatible with that package, the one I mentioned above and createTokenWithCardFormAsync...

Ultimately I would like to attach the token to a customer so that they don't need to put their card details everytime they want to purchase something.

Also at the moment of token creation I do not charge any money, just want to 'keep' their info just like uber does.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customer creation and Charge creation on Stripe is a secret-key only function, therefore cannot be done on your client-side (your mobile app which can only use your publishable key).

Therefore, the flow here is:

1. Create a Token on your app (as you are)
2. Post the token to your backend endpoint
3. Your backend endpoint (written in say, node using `stripe-node`) calls `stripe.customers.create()` with the Token ID, attaching the Token to the Customer
4. Charge creation later also has to happen server-side, not client-side.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer!

When you say backend endpoint you mean like my API? I send the tok\en to my API which will then call the Stripe API?

Comment: Correct! Every Stripe integration has a "client-side" portion (your mobile app or web page) and a "server-side" portion. Stripe operations like creating Customers or Charges happen on the server-side using your Stripe secret key.